# Modifying an IEnumerable type

Tags: c#

I have a a string `IEnumerable` type that I get from the below code.The var groups is an `Enumerable` type which has some string values. Say there are 4 values in groups and in the second position the value is just empty string "" .The question is how can I move it to the 4th ie the end position.I do not want to sort or change any order.Just move the empty "" value whereever it occurs to the last position.

```
List<Item> Items = somefunction();
var groups = Items.Select(g => g.Category).Distinct();
```

Comment: Well... I guess you could do an orderByDescending ?

Comment: I don't want to change the order or sort it.Just make the empty "" value go to the last position.

Comment: Then remove empty value if it exists and add it to the end.

Comment: I think that's what I asked

Comment: So many answers all missing to mention the obvious. As powerful as it is Linq isn't sacred, if a simple for loop is more readable and easier for you to conceive use that instead.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum So where's your answer with the for loop? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly modify the `IEnumerable<>` instance, but you can create a new one:

```
var list = groups.Where(x => x != "").Concat(groups.Where(x => x == ""));
```

Note that in this query, `groups` is iterated twice. This is usually not a good practice for a deferred `IEnumerable<>`, so you should call `ToList()` after the `Distinct()` to eagerly evaluate your LINQ query:

```
var groups = Items.Select(g => g.Category).Distinct().ToList();
```

**EDIT :**

On second thought, there's a much easier way to do this:

```
var groups = Items.Select(g => g.Category).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x == "");
```

Note that this doesn't touch the order of the non-empty elements since `OrderBy` is stable.

Comment: This works perfectly.Creates the new instance and moves the "" to the end without modifying the other order.

Comment: @user505210: I've just added another simplified version. Check my edit ;)

Answer (score 4):

Simply order the results by their string value:

```
List<Item> Items = somefunction();
var groups = Items.Select(g => g.Category).Distinct().OrderByDescending(s => s);
```

Edit (following OP edit):

```
List<Item> Items = somefunction();
var groups = Items.Select(g => g.Category).Distinct();

groups = groups.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    .Concat(groups.Where(s => String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
```

Comment: Why are you still desendingly ordering non empties ?

Comment: @sylon Was a mistake, fixed.

Comment: @digEmAll Sorry again, meant `IsNullOrEmpty`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var groups = Items.Select(g => g.Category).Distinct().OrderByDescending(s =>s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like my query but it should do the job. It selects all items which are not empty and unions it with the items which are empty.

```
var groups = Items.Select(g => g.Category).Distinct()
.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
.Union(Items.Select(g => g.Category).Distinct()
.Where(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like

```
var temp = groups.Where(item => ! String.IsNullOrEmpty(item)).ToList<string>();
while (temp.Count < groups.Count) temp.Add("");
```

Comment: @The down voter : Can you please care to explain what is wrong with this approach apart from it not being the most efficient way of achieving the result ?